# I am making a html canvas game. Type of

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

Hey I am making a responsive canvas. I don't know what's wrong please help me.
There is problem in html or javascript. I dont now.
I dont know the standards keywords. please fix it for me.
i am using Brackets.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #myCanvas {
                border: 2px solid black;
            }
            input {
                border: .5px solid black;
                padding: 2px;
            }

        </style>
        <script>
            function drawRect() {
                var ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2D');
                var x = document.getElementById("x").value;
                var y = document.getElementById("y").value;
                var w = document.getElementById("w").value;
                var h = document.getElementById("h").value;
                ctx.fillStyle = "black";
                ctx.fillRect( x, y, w, h);
                reset()
            }
        </script>   
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
        <br />
        <input id="x" type="number" value="10" step="5" min="0" max="200">
        <input id="y" type="number" value="10" step="5" min="0" max="200">
        <input id="w" type="number" value="10" step="5" min="0" max="400">
        <input id="h" type="number" value="10" step="5" min="0" max="300">
        <button id="mybtn" onclick="drawRect">Draw</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: drawRect does not have parenthesis so does not get called in onclick. Also reset() refers to what function?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.getContext('2d')` instead of `.getContext('2D')`.

Also, `drawRect` does not have parenthesis, as was mentioned by Anthony McGrath

Check this out:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #myCanvas {
                border: 2px solid black;
            }
            input {
                border: .5px solid black;
                padding: 2px;
            }

        </style>
        <script>
            function drawRect() {
                var ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');
                var x = document.getElementById("x").value;
                var y = document.getElementById("y").value;
                var w = document.getElementById("w").value;
                var h = document.getElementById("h").value;
                ctx.fillStyle = "black";
                ctx.fillRect( x, y, w, h);
            }
        </script>   
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
        <br />
        <input id="x" type="number" value="10" step="5" min="0" max="200">
        <input id="y" type="number" value="10" step="5" min="0" max="200">
        <input id="w" type="number" value="10" step="5" min="0" max="400">
        <input id="h" type="number" value="10" step="5" min="0" max="300">
        <button id="mybtn" onclick="drawRect()">Draw</button>
    </body>
</html>
```